# Mathematical Logic Problems

Tags: logic

1. True or false(and why): If **T** is a set of logical sentences which is
   logically contingent and **T'** so that **T'** $\subset$ **T**, then
   **T'** is also logically contingent
2. Prove that $$\phi \lor \psi, \lnot \phi \vdash \psi$$ without using the theorem $$\Gamma\vdashφ \iff \Gamma\vDashφ$$

These are the Axioms that i can use for 2.

- $(1) φ\to(ψ  φ)$
- $(2) (φ\to (ψ \to χ))\to ((φ\to ψ)\to (φ\to χ)$
- $(3) (φ\leftrightarrow ψ)\to (φ\to ψ)$
- $(4) (φ\leftrightarrow ψ)\to (ψ\to φ)$
- $(5) (φ\to ψ)\to ((ψ\to φ)\to (φ\leftrightarrow ψ))$
- $(6) φ\lor ψ\to ψ\lor φ$
- $(7) φ\land ψ\to ψ\land φ$
- $(8) φ\to φ\lor ψ$
- $(9) φ\land ψ\to φ$
- $(10) φ\to (ψ\to φ\land ψ)$
- $(11) (φ\to χ)\land (ψ\to χ)\to (φ\lor ψ\to χ)$
- $(12) (φ\to (ψ\land \neg ψ))\to \neg φ$
- $(13) (φ\land \neg φ)\to ψ$
- $(14) φ\lor \neg φ$

Comment: Which *proof system* (i.e.axioms and rules) are yu using ?

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of your problem ? I think it must be : $φ∨ψ,¬φ⊢ψ$. You cannot prove $φ∨ψ,¬φ⊢φ$ because $φ$ is **not** *logical consequence* of : $φ∨ψ,¬φ$ (i.e.$φ∨ψ,¬φ \nvDash φ$). To prove it, consider a *valuation* $v$ such that $v(\psi) = T$ and $v(\varphi)=F$. With it, we have that $v(\varphi \lor \psi)=v(\lnot \varphi)=T$ but $v(\varphi)=F$; thus it is **not** true that for all valuation which satisfy the formulae $φ∨ψ,¬φ$ also $\varphi$ is satisfied.

Comment: Axiom (1) : $φ→(ψφ)$ does not make sense; it must be $\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 2., we assume that the original OP's formula is wrong (because it is not provable) and that we have to prove  :

> $φ∨ψ,¬φ⊢ψ$.

We assume also the correct form of axiom (1), i.e. :

> $φ \rightarrow (ψ \rightarrow φ)$.

Finally, we assume to be available the *rule of inference* of *modus ponens* :

> from $\varphi$ and $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$, derive $\psi$.

---

We have several possibilities :

- we can prove the *tautology* : $(\varphi \lor \psi) \rightarrow (\lnot \varphi \rightarrow \psi)$, and then use it to conclude with $\psi$ by *modus ponens* twice;

or:

- we can prove the [Disjunctive syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism), i.e. the *tautology* : $\lnot \varphi \rightarrow ((\varphi \lor \psi) \rightarrow \psi)$ and then proceed as above.

A third possibility is based on the proof of some preliminary *lemmas* :

> *Lemma-1* : $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi$.

The proof needs only Ax1 and Ax2 and it is quite easy (usually, it is the first logical theorem of *propositional calculus* to be proved in eevery mathematical logic textbook).

> *Lemma-2* : $\varphi \rightarrow \psi, \psi \rightarrow \sigma \vdash \varphi \rightarrow \sigma$ (*Syllogism*)

*Proof :*

(1) $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ --- assumed

(2) $\psi \rightarrow \sigma$ --- assumed

(3) $\vdash (\psi \rightarrow \sigma) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \sigma))$ --- Ax1

(4) $(\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \sigma))$ --- from (2) and (3) by *modus ponens*

(5) $\vdash (\varphi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \sigma)) \rightarrow ((\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \sigma))$ --- Ax2

(6) $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\varphi \rightarrow \sigma)$ --- from (4) and (5) by *modus ponens*

(7) $\varphi \rightarrow \sigma$ --- from (1) and (6) by *modus ponens*.

> *Lemma-3* : $\lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$

*Proof :*

(1) $\lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi \rightarrow (\lnot \varphi \land \varphi)$ --- from Ax10 : $φ→(ψ→φ∧ψ)$ by *mp*

(2) $\lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi \rightarrow (\varphi \land \lnot \varphi)$ --- from (1) and Ax7 : $φ∧ψ→ψ∧φ$ using *Lemma-2*

(3) $\lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$ --- from (2) and Ax13 : $(φ∧¬φ)→ψ$ using *Lemma-2*.

> Now for the proof of :
>
> > $\varphi \lor \psi, \lnot \varphi \vdash \psi$

(1) $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \land (\psi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\varphi \lor \psi \rightarrow \psi)$ --- from Ax11 : $(φ→χ)∧(ψ→χ)→(φ∨ψ→χ)$

(2) $\lnot \varphi \vdash (\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \land (\psi \rightarrow \psi)$ --- from *Lemma-3* and *Lemma-1* by Ax10 and *mp* twice

(3) $\lnot \varphi \vdash (\varphi \lor \psi \rightarrow \psi)$ --- from (1) and (2) by *mp*

(4) $\lnot \varphi, \varphi \lor \psi \vdash \psi$ --- from (3) by *mp*.

---

---

About 1., assuming that *logically contingent* means that the set is *satisfiable* but not "tautological", i.e. we can find a *valuation* $v$ such that the set **T** is *not* satisfied, the answer is : **FALSE**.

Consider the set **T** = $\{ \lnot p \lor p, q \}$. It is *logically contingent* because we can use the *valuation* $v$ such that $v(p)=v(q)=F$ and the set **T** is not satisfied.

But its subset **T'** = $\{ \lnot p \lor p \}$ is "tautological", i.e.we cannot find a valuation which "falsify" it, because $\lnot p \lor p$ is a *tautology*.

Comment: I think you made the same error as the OP in your first line, namely, stating that the proof of $φ∨ψ,¬φ⊢φ$ is quite simple. I take it you mean $φ∨ψ,¬φ⊢\psi$.

Comment: About 1. In my notes "Logically contingent" means that it is not a contradiction, so i guess that the assumption is correct. For curiosity's sake, if **T** was a tautology then this sentence would be true, right?

About 2. I don't understand where you got (2). Is it derived from other axioms or is it generally true? I am asking because i have a list of 14 axioms to use in this (and some more identical) exercises and i can't find this one. Although i can see how it's true, i have to explain (mainly to my self) how i got it.

Comment: @Dim.Tsach. - YES; if **T** is a "tautological" set of sentences, also each subset of it is.

Comment: @amWhy Actually it is correct. I triple checked and my OP is correct about 2.

Comment: @Dim.Tsach I was referring to the original request to prove that $\phi \lor \psi, \lnot \phi \vdash \phi$. Both your post and this post have since been edited. The typo is the rightside, you had $\phi$ on the right, and what we need is $\psi$ on the right.